# How can I integrate authentication between laravel applications?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, integration

I'm building a series of web applications to use in a small business. We will be using laravel framework to build these applications. The first app will manage users, authentication and authorization for all future applications. 
I have 2 doubts:

1. Is there some best pratice / model for this auth integration? How can I tell app B that the user is authenticated and has access to it? I want to build different laravel apps in order to make it easier to maintain, but (at least for now) they'll run in the same server.
2. Is it possible to make this integration with another php, non-laravel app? I have one legacy webapp, I'm trying to write the session data that authenticates it inside my laravel code and redirecting the user to the app, but the session data apparently isn't "persisting".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities, you could persist sessions on your database and all your applications use the same database, you could create a RESTful API an use OAuth with JWT for authentication and do requests to your first app to make sure the user is authenticated. First you have to narrow down your limitations in terms of hardware. For that reason I'm voting to close down this question.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are building a micro service architecture if you follow this methodology there is no reason your apps or services even have to be written in the same language as long as they and all interact using RESTful services.

More reading:
http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html